# Loop through query and have an array of location

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an SQL query like so:

```
SELECT name, rbl.locationlabel FROM `pages` INNER JOIN locations as rbl ON rbl.locationId = pages.locationId
```

This will return a list of names and a locationlabel, locationlabel will either be 'location A', 'location B', or 'location C' what I have is this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT name, rbl.locationlabel FROM `pages` INNER JOIN locations as rbl ON rbl.locationId = pages.locationId");
                $results = array();
                $results['location'] = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        $results[] = $row;
                }
                return $results;
```

this will loop through the results and put it into an array, what I am looking to do is have either another array or an array inside the results array to have each location and have the names that is assigned to the location.

much help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide a concrete example output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `name` field is unique, you could simply have:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $results[$row['name']] = $row;
}
```

But if you get repeated names, then you'd need some fancier logic, like creating subarrays:

```
   $results[$row['name']][] = $row;
```

Comment: I think the user wants an array whose index would be the name of locations and contents would be the name of the people belonging to that location.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","abc1");

if($con)
{

$i=0;

$query="select distinct location from locations";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($re=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$x[]=$re;
}

}

$m=array();
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{

$query="SELECT name FROM `pages` INNER JOIN locations as rbl ON rbl.locationId = pages.locationId";
$z=$x[$i]['location'];
echo $query;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($re=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
foreach($re as $q)
$m["'".$z."'"][]=$q;
}



}


print_r($m);


?>
```

It stores the names inside an array whose index is the name of the location.

Sample Output:

```
 Array ( ['A'] => Array ( [0] => John [1] => Jim [2] => Jack) 
['B'] => Array ( [0] => Joseph [1] => Mary ) 
['C'] => Array ( [0] => Bale [1] => Cyrus [2] => Mike [3] => Rhode ) )
```

You can access the elements using `name_of_array['location_name'][number of name records]`

Hope it helps.